# Django Restful Api of ManytoMany models to show the foreign objects

Tags: django, restful-url

The "Brand" object is foreign key of "company",they are ManytoMany relationship,and Brand object exists the field "company_Group"

the models are as follows:

```
class Brand(models.Model):
      Company_Group = models.ManyToManyField(Company)
      Brand_Group = models.CharField(u'Brand Group',max_length=255, default="")
      Pref_Brand_Name_Flg = models.CharField(u'Preferred Name Flag',max_length=255, default="")
      Pref_Brand_Name = models.CharField(u'Preferred Name',max_length=255, default="")
      PrimaryContact = models.ForeignKey(UserRole, null=True, blank=True) 



class Company(models.Model):
      Pref_Company_Name_Flg = models.CharField(u'Preferred Name Flag',max_length=255, default="")
      Pref_Company_Name = models.CharField(u'Preferred Name',max_length=255, default="")
      Company_Type = models.CharField(u'Company Type',max_length=255, default="")
```

serializers

```
class BrandSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Brand
        fields = '__all__'
```

the Serializer as follows ,`data_export_setting.Company_form_stand` is the field as

```
class CompanySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    Brand = BrandSerializer(source='brand', read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        Company_form_stand=['id', 'Brand', 'Company_Type','Company_Name','company_Name_SC']
        fields = data_export_setting.Company_form_stand
        depth = 2

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Company.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.__dict__.update(**validated_data)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

the viewset are as follows

```
class BrandViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
     queryset = Brand.objects.all()
     serializer_class = BrandSerializer
     model = Brand

     def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
         if 'data' in kwargs:
             data = kwargs['data']
             if isinstance(data, list):
                 kwargs['many'] = True
    return super(BrandViewSet, self).get_serializer(*args, **kwargs)


class CompanyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
      queryset = Company.objects.all()
      serializer_class = CompanySerializer
```

and I want to show the company objects with Brand objects ,however,it seems to ignore the brand object and its field

[image: the field ignore the company!]

appreciate any help ,thanks

Comment: Company doesn't have a `brand` field, so I'm not sure where you're expecting that data to come from.

Comment: the relationship of company and brand is ManytoMany,so i want  to show the brand object in the company  ,Do you have any ways to show  it  without changing models ,Just like the form with adding some fields not in the model ,thanks ~

Comment: But there's no such thing as "the brand object". There are *many* brand objects related to each company.

Comment: sorry,it's my fault ! I express my view implicitly~ I forget to tell the attribute of ManytoMany ~Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
Brand = BrandSerializer(source='brand_set', read_only=True, many=True)
```

Since, you have defined the field relation as `ManyToMany`, more than one `Brand` objects are related to a single `Company` instance. By using the reverse relation, you can access them in your serializer, and `many=True` lets the serializer handle multiple objects in the relation.

Comment: Yes,it works !
by the way,I want to choose some fields to show ,How I to do it ?  Thanks in advance~

Comment: You could choose which fields you want to show in the `fields` attribute in the `Meta` class of your serializer.

Comment: I use the following Serializer ,however ,it seems not to work~ 

"class CompanySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    Brand = BrandSerializer(source='brand_set', read_only=True, many=True)
    Brand_Name = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='Brand.Name', read_only=True) 
    class Meta:
        model = Company     
       fields=['id','Brand','Brand_Name','Company_Type','Company_Name','Company_Name_SC']

Comment: What do you mean "not workin"?? Which are the fields you want to show? which of them you don't?

Comment: for example 
I want to that  Brand object only show  "Brand_Name" ,however it shows all the fields 
I use the above way but it seems to not to work

Comment: Then you only need to write a separate serializer for Brand object use the same in the CompanySerializer.